# Ошибка при создании картинки из массива байт

Tags: c#, wpf

Пытаюсь сохранить картинку из полученного массива, но получаю ArgumentException. Как мне исправить эту ошибку?

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
{
    using(var img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms))
    {
        img.Save("img.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
}
```

Comment: а кроме `ArgumentException` в тексте исключения что было написано? Может у вас в `imageBytes` null пришел или набор байт не соответствует ни одному из поддерживаемых форматов? на чем гадать будем?

Answer (score 2):

Судя по документации, кидать исключение [`ArgumentException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.argumentexception(v=vs.110).aspx) вашем коде может [`Image.FromStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/93z9ee4x(v=vs.110).aspx). Исключение говорит, что:

> Поток не является допустимым форматом изображения

Это значит, что ваш массив байт не является поддерживаемы форматом изображения или изображением вообще. Смотрите выше по коду откуда пришел ваш массив байт и что он из себя представляет.

Comment: Массив байт картинки получен из File.ReadAllBytes

Comment: Попробовал считать картинку вот так, но все равно не появляется та же ошибка:
'System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("img.png");
                        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                            imageBytes = ms.ToArray();
                        }'

Comment: Из документации: "Класс не поддерживает альфа-прозрачность в растровые изображения. Чтобы включить альфа-прозрачность, используйте изображения PNG с 32 битами на пиксел."

Comment: @Артем Оконечников Я это видел, но мне и не нужна альфа-прозрачность, я хочу вообще любые картинки формата png и jpg передавать

Comment: @ElRabbito Может, вам проще просто копировать файлы? Посмотрите [File.Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/c6cfw35a(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Артем Оконечников Я передаю файл по сети, так не сработает :D

Comment: @ElRabbito если вам нужно получить `MemoryStream` из файла, [то это одно](https://pastebin.com/t43n6fYG), если читать изображения в Drawing.Image то нужно соблюдать формат изобраений, который, судя по всему у вас неверный.

Comment: @Артем Оконечников Я выше привел код, которым я пытаюсь получить массив, там я сохраняю картинку в стрим вместе с форматом.

Comment: @ElRabbito файл на диске не в формате, который поддерживает класс `System.Drawing.Image`. Все версии вашего кода используют этот класс (тот, который пишет в стрим и тот который пишет на диск). Если вам нужно читать файлы (любые) в MemoryStream то используйте тот код, что я вам дал (https://pastebin.com/t43n6fYG) если вам нужен Drawing.Image то разбирайтесь с форматом изображений, которые читаете.

Comment: @Артем Оконечников мне нужно передавать именно изображения. Попробовал сделать, как предложили вы, но все равно получаю ошибку [ссылка](https://pastebin.com/92xeNftx)